# How to reverse order of pandas string column

Tags: python, pandas, string, reverse

I have a tennis dataset that looks similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

player_name = ['Novak Djokovic','Rafael Nadal','Roger Federer','Andy Murray']
match_id = [202, 202, 203, 203]
score = ['6-3 5-7 6-4', '6-3 5-7 6-4', '6-4 7-6', '6-4 7-6']
outcome = [1,0,1,0]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'player_name': player_name,
        'match_id': match_id,
         'score': score,
         'outcome':outcome
    })

df["sets"]= df["score"].str.split(" ", n = 3, expand = False)
df['set1_score'] = df['sets'].str[0]
df['set2_score'] = df['sets'].str[1]
df['set3_score'] = df['sets'].str[2]
```

The outcome variable equates to a value of 1 with a win and a value of 0 for a loss.  Currently, the score is written from the perspective of the winner.  I want to be able to switch the order of the set1_score, set2_score, set3_score columns conditioned on the value of 0 (ie: for the loser of the match).

So, I would ideally like for the data frame to look like this:

```
player_name    match_id    score         outcome    sets            set1_score    set2_score   set3_score
Novak Djokovic 202         6-3 5-7 6-4   1          [6-3, 5-7, 6-4] 6-3             5-7          6-4
Rafel Nadal    202         6-3 5-7 6-4   0          [6-3, 5-7, 6-4] 3-6             7-5          4-6
Roger Federer  203         6-4 7-6       1          [6-4, 7-6]      6-4             7-6          NaN
Andy Murray    203         6-4 7-6       0          [6-4, 7-6]      4-6             6-7          NaN
```

How should I go about this process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `outcome` as a boolean mask and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)/reverse the scores :

```
rev = df["score"].replace("(\d)-(\d)", r"\2-\1", # here we reverse
            regex=True).str.split() # but we don't expand yet

scores = df["score"].str.split().where(df["outcome"].astype(bool), rev)

out = pd.concat(
    [
        df, df["score"].str.split().rename("sets"),
        scores.apply(pd.Series).rename(lambda i: f"set{i+1}_score", axis=1)
    ], axis=1
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

      player_name  match_id        score  outcome             sets set1_score set2_score set3_score
0  Novak Djokovic       202  6-3 5-7 6-4        1  [6-3, 5-7, 6-4]        6-3        5-7        6-4
1    Rafael Nadal       202  6-3 5-7 6-4        0  [6-3, 5-7, 6-4]        3-6        7-5        4-6
2   Roger Federer       203      6-4 7-6        1       [6-4, 7-6]        6-4        7-6        NaN
3     Andy Murray       203      6-4 7-6        0       [6-4, 7-6]        4-6        6-7        NaN

[4 rows x 8 columns]
```